# IE change div content

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I need to show dynamic content on div. The content is updated every second. I try these codes, they are not working for IE :

```
jQuery('#test').html("end"); // this works normal with opera , with html tags
// or
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "End"; // this doesnt work normal in opera with html tags
// or
$('test').text('end');
```

I am testing with IE 8.

Comment: You're missing a `#` in the last one. Anyway, why are you talking about opera since you're testing it and have problem on IE?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `$('#test').html("bananas");` will work in IE6+.

Comment: I need it work in opera , chrome and FireFox , IE. I dont know what happend , but it is working now. I have not changed any thing. that is good . thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

Provided you change the third to `$('#test').text('end');`, all three should work fine in IE8.

Comment: There must be some other factor, @SamirMemmedov. The code as presented in your question (excepting the missing `#`) is correct.

Comment: Nick I think your answer should work, but it is not working here. I think I am using prototype that is why those examples not working with IE.